# Spring Data REST Events Not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have tried to configure spring data rest event as per follows.All classes are in package `org.springbootjpa`

Events: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

Following is my code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(
                DemoApplication.class, args);
        String[] beanNames = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }

    }

    @Bean
    GroupEventHandler groupEventHandler() {
        return new GroupEventHandler();
    }
}
```

Event Handler

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(UserGroup.class)
public class GroupEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void handleGroupSave(UserGroup group) {
        System.out.println("Inside handleGroupSave ....");
    }

    @HandleAfterSave
    public void handleAfterSave(UserGroup group) {
        System.out.println("Inside handleAfterSave ....");
    }

}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
public class UserGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long groupId;

    @Column
    private String groupName;
..
}
```

When I post an entry to the userGroups link the listener is not getting triggered.

```
post --data "{groupId:1,groupName:'group1'}"
```

Comment: What is the package your `DemoApplication` is in and the package of the `DemoConfig`. Suggesting instead of using `DemoConfig` simply add the `@Bean` method to the `DemoApplication`.

Comment: They were in the same package .. However I have changed as you have suggested .. Still the same result

Comment: Aren't you listening for the wrong events? A POST will create an entry and I suspect that a `@HandleBeforeCreate` is called instead of  save, which is for updates i..e PUT.

Comment: I think on POST requests only create events are fired ('@HandleBeforeCreate'), try your events with PUT request.

Comment: Yes .. That's it .. I was listening to the wrong event .. HandleBeforeCreate works for me ..

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments the `HandleBeforeCreate` should be called in the case of POST request. The `HandleBeforeSave` event will be fired on PUT request.