# differences between JPA @EntityListeners , @PrePersist and Spring @RepositoryEventHandler, @HandleBeforeSave

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I did some research but was not able to find what is a differences between

```
JPA @EntityListeners , @PrePersist
```

and

```
Spring @RepositoryEventHandler, @HandleBeforeSave
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually after more searching I found this answer 
stackoverflow.com/a/31155291/1780517

It seems that there is also one VERY BIG different, @HandleBeforeSave called on Controller POST method and not on repository save. 
So  @RepositoryEventHandler should be used only if you want  handle events from controller (PUT, POST, GET with@HandleBeforeSave, @HandleBeforeCreate ..) and @EntityListeners should be used for repository method save,delete, update with @PreUpdate , @PreRemove and so on..

Answer (score 7):

`@HandleBeforeSave` only works when an Entity is saved through a Spring Data repository. `@PrePersist` will be trigger if you use `EntityManager::persist()` and if you use `JPARepository::save()`, since it calls persist.

The nice thing with `@RepositoryEventHandler`+`@HandleBeforeSave`is that your `@HandleBeforeSave` method is defined inside a spring bean, so you can interact with other spring beans. `@EntityListeners` and `@PrePersist` can only access the state of the current Entity when operating in a J2SE environment. In J2EE you can `@Inject` beans into a `@EntityListeners` because the JPA subsystem and CDI  are both managed by the same Container.

Comment: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31155291/1780517 and It seems that there is also one VERY BIG different,      @HandleBeforeSave called on Controller POST method and not on repository save.

Comment: The example you reference uses Spring DATA *REST*, when you POST it will call the save method of the repository internally.